# como cerrar un menu con la tecla de "atras o volver" de un dispositivo movil

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, web

Mi proyecto es de una pagina web única que despliega o abre un menú de tipo `overlay`, el cual cubre toda la pantalla, al ser un proyecto destinado preferentemente a **dispositivos móviles**.

Necesito que al dar el botón "atrás o volver" del dispositivo móvil cierre el menú y no cierre la pagina o se salga.
Abra alguna forma de interrumpir la acción del botón "atrás o volver" del dispositivo móvil para designar la función de cerrar el menú.

Espero y me ayuden saludos

Comment: Lea por favor [ask] y como redactar un [mcve]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Prueba [modificando el historial](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/History_API#a%C3%B1adiendo_y_modificando_entradas_del_historial)

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que debes hacer, es agregar un nuevo estado al historial, el cual funciona como una Pila. Esto te permitirá retroceder al estado original

```
history.pushState(null , null, "#nombredelmodal")
```

Si te fijas se ingresó un nuevo estado, que tiene una nueva URL, cual será algo así: http://mipagina.com/#nombredelmodal

He utilizado un hash para poder utilizar el evento hashchange, el cual detectará cualquier cambia en el hash de la URL

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange',ReadHash, false);
function ReadHash() {
    if (location.hash === '') {
        // cierro modal
    }
    else {
        // abro modal
    }
}
```

Dejo un ejemplo completo usando bootstrap

```js
function PushState(modal) {
    history.pushState(null , null, modal)
    return true;
}

window.addEventListener('hashchange',ReadHash, false);
function ReadHash() {
    if (location.hash === '') {
        bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(document.querySelector(".modal")).hide();
    }
    else {
        var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.querySelector(location.hash));
        myModal.show();
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onclick="return PushState('#exampleModal')">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button onclick="history.back()">history.back()</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```